# Dockerizing 2 separate dependant services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I currently have a VM running 2 services. A frontend httpd/apache2 service that proxies all request to my backend services.

My bankend service only listens on `127.0.0.1:7878`. This means it is only accessible via localhost. Thats the reason why Im using a frontend so that I can use that to proxy my requests to `127.0.0.1:7878`

So my apache2 config on the VM looks like :

```
root@vm:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# cat backend.conf
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName my.domain.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:7878/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7878/

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl_cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl_cert.key

</VirtualHost>
```

Now I want to dockerize both services and deploy them using `docker-compose`

I have setup my backend service like :

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build: backend/.
    ports:
     - "7878:7878"
```

And my `backend/` folder has all the required files for my backend service including the Dockerfile. I am able to successfully build by docker image and can run it successfully. When I exec into the pod, I can successfully run `curl` commands towards `127.0.0.1:7878/some-end-point`

Now I need to dockerize the frontend service too. It could be apache or it could even be nginx. But Im not sure how both containers will interac with each other given that my backend services ONLY listens on `127.0.0.1`

If I extend my docker-compose file like :

```
version: '3'
    services:
      backend:
        build: backend/.
        ports:
         - "7878:7878"
      frontend:
        build: frontend/.
        ports:
         - "80:80"
         - "443:443"
```

I believe it will spin up its own network and my backend service wont be accessible using `127.0.0.1:7878`

So in this case, whats the best approach ? How do I use docker-compose to spin up different containers on the SAME network so that they share `127.0.0.1` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that as you describe: the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 is a magic address that always means "me", and in a Docker context it will mean "this container".

It's easy enough to [set up a private Docker-internal network for your containers](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/); in fact, Docker Compose will do this automatically for you.  Your backend service must be listening on 0.0.0.0 to be accessible from other containers.  You're not required to set externally published `ports:` on your container (or use the `docker run -p` option), though.  If you don't, then your container will only be reachable from other containers on the same Docker-internal network, using the service name in the `docker-compose.yml` file as a DNS name, on whatever port the process inside the container happens to be listening on.

A minimal example of this could look like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: 'my/proxy:20181220.01'
    environment:
      BACKEND_URL: 'http://backend'
      BIND_ADDRESS: '0.0.0.0:80'
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
  backend:
    image: 'my/backend:20181220.01'
    environment:
      BIND_ADDRESS: '0.0.0.0:80'
```

From outside Docker, you can reach the proxy at `http://server-hostname.example.com:8080`.  From inside Docker, the two hostnames `proxy` and `backend` will resolve to Docker-internal addresses, and we've set both services (via a hypothetical environment variable setup) to listen on the ordinary HTTP port 80.

Comment: So to conclude, right now the backend service listening on `127.0.0.1` will not work. I definitely have to listen on either a specific IP address or on `0.0.0.0`. Is that correct ?

Comment: Also Docker assigns the per-container IP address (it's not fixed) so you basically have to use 0.0.0.0.